# Check if date has timezone given

Tags: javascript, momentjs

If datetime has timezone parse timezone and then convert to UTC:

e.g. `convert('2018-01-05T17:04:43+04:00')` => `2018-01-05T13:04:43Z`

If datetime does not have timezone convert to UTC:

e.g. `convert('2018-01-05T17:04:43')` => `2018-01-05T17:04:43Z`

How can I do this reliably? Maybe with moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If datetime has timezone parse timezone and then convert to UTC* and *If datetime does not have timezone <del>convert to</del> **parse it as** UTC* is exactly what [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) does.

Here a live sample:

```js
var arr = [
  '2018-01-05T16:29:00.000-04:00',
  '2018-01-05T16:29:00.000+00:00',
  '2018-01-05T16:29:00.000Z',
  '2018-01-05T16:29:00.000'
];
arr.forEach( (s) => {
  console.log( moment.utc(s).format() ) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you seen this page ? https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

You can parse and change timezones with that. My suggestion is to force every date to the same timezone (your timezone for example or another standard timezone) and then compare dates in the same timezone.

Hope this helps